# When value is 0, change checkbox - input only accept digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox that when clicked has an input value of 1. When it is unchecked the value is 0. That is ok.

The input only accepts digits, the validation is ok.
I want it to work in a way that when the value is 0 the checkbox is not checked.

My example sometimes fails when I play with values of one digit, or more than two.

```
  jQuery(document).on('keypress keyup blur', 'input.e-qty', function (event) {
        if ((((event.which > 47) && (event.which < 58)) || (event.which == 13)) ) {
            var qty = jQuery(this).val();
            if(qty.length == 1 && qty == 0){
                jQuery('.product').trigger('click');
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;        
    });


    jQuery(document).on("change", ".product", function () {
        var id = this.id.split("_").pop();
        var qty = jQuery('#qty_' + id);

        qty.val(+this.checked);

    });
```

https://jsbin.com/patekocuya/1

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can use the `attr` property, since attributes could be altered at runtime also, therefore your code would look like this..

```
jQuery(document).on('keypress keyup blur', 'input.e-qty', function (event) {
        if ((((event.which > 47) && (event.which < 58)) || (event.which == 13)) ) {
            var qty = Number(jQuery(this).val());

            if(qty == 0){

                $('.product').attr('checked', true);

            }else{

                $('.product').attr('checked', false);
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;        
    });
```

**Note**

Also take note that checking if you are working with classes it is best to tell the page which checkbox you are referring to since class referencing returns a collection. using this method you could modify the `HTMLInputElement`s property directly,

therefore your code becomes -

```
 $('.product')[0].checked = true;
 or
 $('.product')[0].checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function instead of click

1. Add else statement with not equal 0 with checked true
2. Just use `parseFloat` for the numeric problem

**Updated**

https://jsbin.com/coqutuzizo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
 jQuery(document).on('keypress keyup keydown blur', 'input.e-qty', function (event) {
    if ((((event.which > 47) && (event.which < 58)) || (event.which == 13) || (event.which == 8)) ) {
        var qty = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
        if(qty === 0 || !$.trim($(this).val())){
            jQuery('.product').prop('checked',false);
        }else{
            jQuery('.product').prop('checked',true);

        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;        
});
```

Comment: I suggest you need to update your conditions with triple equals ===that gives you an exact match. Then try your function.

Comment: I think this solution is good! I would recommend adding maxlength attribute to your input field so only one number is allowed :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir i just parse the value of the input .its now be a number.i think its should ok for both of yours

Comment: working but, try this: 1) press checkbox 2)delete 1 and write 06 for example 3) delete the number 6, only have the value 0, but the checkbox is not unselect. @Wimanicesir

Comment: because `backspace` key value not perform the condition.Try latest updated fiddle @Alexd2

Answer (score 0):

Is this what [you are looking for](https://jsfiddle.net/qwy7ausj/)  https://jsfiddle.net/qwy7ausj/

```
jQuery(document).on('keypress keyup blur', 'input.e-qty', function(event) {

var qty = jQuery(this).val();
if (qty != 0) {

    jQuery('.product').prop('checked', true);
} else {
    jQuery('.product').prop('checked', false);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate `keypress` and `keyup` otherwise you will get a double value.

Here i made you an example.

```js
jQuery(document).on('keypress', 'input.e-qty', function (event) {
        if ((((event.which > 47) && (event.which < 58)) || (event.which == 13)) ) 
            return true;

        return false;        
    });


jQuery(document).on('keyup', 'input.e-qty', function (event) {
            var qty = $(this).val();
            if(qty != "" ){
               var i = parseInt(qty);
                  jQuery('.product').prop("checked", i>0).trigger("change")
                }
    });
    
   jQuery(document).on("change", ".product", function () {
        var id = this.id.split("_").pop();
        jQuery('#qty_' + id).val(+this.checked).focus().select(); ;
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_1" class="product">
<input type="text" class="e-qty" name="qty" id="qty_1" value="0">
```

Comment: Can't insert nothing value @alen-toma

Comment: Well its working for me, i insert 1 (checked) insert 0(unchecket)

Comment: see this example the other friend https://jsbin.com/coqutuzizo/1/edit?html,js,console,output